# Jekyll: Empty HTML attributes

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I mentioned that when using HTML attributes with no value in Jekyll (inside a *.md) like this

```
<div vc-recaptcha key="{{site.recaptcha-sitekey}}" ng-model="data.recaptcha"></div>
```

it's parsed as

```
<div vc-recaptcha="" key="..." ng-model="data.recaptcha"></div>
```

Look at the `vc-recaptcha` attribute.
How do I prevent Jekyll from doing this?

I also tried to put it into a separate file and include it by `{% include recaptcha.html %}` but this doesn't work either (same result).

Also putting it between `{%raw%}` and `{%endraw%}` doesn't help.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you put `vc-recaptcha=vc-recaptcha`?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I have no clue why but this produces an escaped version: &lt;div vc-recaptcha=vc-recaptcha key=... ng-model="data.recaptcha"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;

Comment: Are you sure it works without = anything?

Comment: `{{ site.recaptcha-sitekey | inspect }}` ?

Comment: @marcanuy attribute foo="bar" is untouched and parsed correctly but not without an empty attribut. foo becomes foo="".

Comment: @DavidJacquel the jekyll var is not the case. if i write anything there directly the problem is still present.

Comment: Why exactly is this undesired behaviour? Seems like a valid replacement to me. I think an attribute without a value can be written in both ways.

Comment: So, a repository url maybe ?